# write a C++ code to get the hostname

Tags: hostname, c++

I want to write a C++ Code to get the full information on all the host name, and ip address and sub net mask of computer that has been added to the domain control.

Comment: This should be placed in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

**gethostname** will give you the name of the current host

**gethostbyname** looks up the host with a particular name and will give you the address

```
man 3 gethostname
man 3 gethostbyname
```

Or you can extract the information you need from the system like this :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
  system( "ifconfig -a | grep inet | "
      "sed 's/\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\)\\([ ]*[^ ]*\\).*$/\\1 \\2/' "
      " > networkinfos.txt" ) ;
}
```

Comment: The second idea assumes a POSIX system. gethostname/gethostbyname also work on Windows.